# Passing and updating an array of scores by increasing with given percentage

Tags: java, arrays, function, percentage

```
public class ScoreCard {

private double[] scores;
/**
 * 
 * @param val
 * @param low
 * @param high
 * @return low if val < low, 
 * high if val > high, 
 * val if val is between low and high
 */
private double constrain(double val, int low, int high) {
    if (val < low)
        return low;
    if (val > high)
        return high;
    return val;
    }

.
.
.
.

/**
 * update each score so it increases by given percentage. For example,
 * if score = {60.0, 90.0} before the method is called, it should
 * become {72.0, 100.0} after the method is called with parameter 20.
 * Note: 90.0 increased by 20% is 108, but scores should be constrained between
 * 0 and 100. So, 100.
 * @param percentage
 */

public void scale(double percentage) {
    for (int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
        percentage = scores[i] / 100.0 * percentage;
        scores[i] += constrain(percentage, 0, 100);
        }
    }
```

I've been stuck again on a little piece of code for a project. I am failing the JUnit tests when I try and pass this function. It seems to be correctly updating array with given percentage (10%) but instead of each item updating by the given percent, it seems to divide the percentage between the items inside the array, giving me ugly numbers.

Any assistance would be greatly appreicated!

Comment: If you want to update each score individually, why do you have a `sum` variable that gets increased for each score (by the previous sum)?

Comment: what is role of constrain() in code

Comment: I added the "constrain" function to the code

Comment: @dosdebug if `sum == 0` then the result of the calculation will be zero. No exceptions here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you changing the value of percentage in the loop?
I would do something like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
    scores[i] = constrain(scores[i]*(1+percentage/100), 0, 100);
}
```

Comment: So my logic had percentage constantly updated in loop?

Answer (score 0):

```
public void scale(double percentage) {
    for (int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
        percentage = scores[i] / 100.0 * percentage;

        scores[i] =(scores[i]+percentage)>=100?100:(scores[i]+percentage);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Just code with no explanations is not considered a good answer. Also what is the purpose of the unused variable `double sum = 0;`?

Comment: @UnholySheep The "sum" variable was old code before I had changed it, my bad. You are correct with questioning its logic.

Comment: Thanks for all your help guys, seems like I have it passing Junits now.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @DimaSan , I am new here. Thank you. I will keep it  in my mind.